# Rails Object's Attributes not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration

I'm relatively new to Rails (4, Ruby 2.0) and currently have a has_many + belongs_to association that I'm working with. The association that I'm trying to model is a 'Day' having several 'Timeslots' and each Timeslot belonging to a Day.

My models look like this:

Day.rb

```
class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :timeslots
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

Timeslot.rb

```
class Timeslot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  belongs_to :day
  validates_presence_of :start_time
  validates_presence_of :end_time
  validates_presence_of :day_id
end
```

Schemas for Day and Timeslot:

```
  create_table "days", force: true do |t| 
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end 

  create_table "timeslots", force: true do |t| 
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.time     "start_time"
    t.time     "end_time"
    t.integer  "day_id"
  end
```

The issue that I'm seeing is that I can't get a Timeslot object to save to the DB correctly:

In the console:

```
d = Day.new
=> #<Day id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, date: nil> 
d.id = 20140322
=> 20140322 
d.save
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (22.2ms)  INSERT INTO "days" ("created_at", "date", "id", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?,     ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 22 Mar 2014 21:28:27 PDT -07:00], ["id", 20140322], ["updated_at", Sat, 22 Mar 2014 21:28:27 PDT -07:00]]
 (6.8ms)  commit transaction
 => true

 Day.all
 Day Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "days".* FROM "days"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Day id: 20140322, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]> 
 t = Timeslot.new
 => #<Timeslot id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, start_time: nil, end_time: nil, day_id: nil> 
 t.start_time = Time.now
 2014-03-22 21:28:52 -0700 
 t.end_time = Time.now
 2014-03-22 21:28:57 -0700 
 t.day_id = 20140322
 => 20140322 
 t.save
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
SQL (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "timeslots" ("created_at", "day_id", "end_time", "start_time",  "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 22 Mar 2014 21:29:06 PDT -07:00], ["day_id", 20140322], ["end_time", 2014-03-22 21:28:57 -0700], ["start_time", 2014-03-22 21:28:52 -0700], ["updated_at", Sat, 22 Mar 2014 21:29:06 PDT -07:00]]
(7.6ms)  commit transaction
=> true



# Here's the problem
Day.all
Day Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "days".* FROM "days"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Day id: 20140322, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]> 
2.0.0-p247 :015 > Timeslot.all
Timeslot Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "timeslots".* FROM "timeslots"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Timeslot id: 2, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, start_time: nil, end_time: nil, day_id: 20140322>]> 
a = Day.all.first
Day Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "days".* FROM "days" ORDER BY "days"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<Day id: 20140322, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
a.timeslots
Timeslot Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "timeslots".* FROM "timeslots" WHERE "timeslots"."day_id" = ?  [["day_id", 20140322]]
```

=> #]>

The fact is that the Timeslot objects just don't seem be created properly. I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: You're not assigning any days to timeslots when they are created.  You need to do `t.day = d` after `t = Timeslot.new` to assign the created `d` to `t`.

Comment: So doing t.day_id = <dayId> wouldn't be enough? Also why aren't the start_time and end_time values for t getting saved on t.save despite having been assigned legal values?

Comment: Doing t.day = d; t.save; after setting the start and end times in t still shows [#<Timeslot id: 2, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, start_time: nil, end_time: nil, day_id: 20140322>]> 

Where the start_time and end_time aren't getting written :/

Comment: my bad.  I did not see that.  I confused myself seeing a "number only" date.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things I don't understand in your files, and I think you should use the ruby command line tools to generate your files to be sure not to do any mistake. For instance, your created_At and updated_at are not normal, they should be filled automatically and they are not.

I suggest you delete your files and launch those commands

```
rails g model day calendar:references
rails g model timeslot start_time:time end_time:time  day:references
```

Then you add your association to the models

```
class Day < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :timeslots
  belongs_to :calendar
end
class Timeslot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events
  belongs_to :day
  validates_presence_of :start_time
  validates_presence_of :end_time
  # validates_presence_of :day_id #Remove this line for now
end
```

And you can launch `rake db:migrate` and try again (by the way `Day.all.first` is the same as `Day.first` and instead of `t.day_id = ...`, try `t.day = Day.first`